# Pandas sort_index numerically, not lexicographically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having some issues with sorting a pandas dataframe.

`sort_index(axis=0)` results in the dataframe sorting the index as 1 10 11 12 13... etc.

While `sort_index(axis=1)` seems to work for the first couple of rows and then it gets completely disordered.

I simply cannot wrap my head around what is going on. I want a simply numerical sorting of my indices, it seems that it ought to be the standard setting for sort_index.

Comment: Try a different sorting algorithm (`sort_index(kind='mergesort', axis=1)` for example).

Comment: I've tried everything that I can come up with... I simply do not get it and I cannot find anything on either stackoverflow or google.
Say I have a data frame with 4000 entries, the incides go from 1 to 4000 but they aren't sorted numerically. How do I sort them from 1 to 4000, numercially. Nothing I'm trying works - this seems like the simplest thing in the world.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html
Might as well be in Greek for me. I don't understand what "if not None, sort on values in specified index level(s)" means....?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a **[mcve]**. Otherwise, the only answer you can expect is a guess.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 types of index, either row index `(axis=0)` or columns index `(axis=1)`

you are just arranging columns by name when you use `axis=1`. it does not reorder each row by values. check your columns names after your `sort_index(axis=1)` and you will understang

Comment: Ah I see, of course. That part makes sense now. I still do not see why the sorting doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extracting the index values with

```
df['indices']=df.index.values.tolist()
```

and sorting the whole dataframe by the new column. It works, but it's ugly and I feel like I'm missing something very basic with sort_index()

Answer (score 0):

You might have the index as a string type.

I was having this issue after using the `groupby()` function. I fixed the problem by changing the column that later became my index to an `int()` with:

`df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype(int)` .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to "humansort" rather than strictly and alphanumerically sort dataframe indices and column labels. The indices in my dataframe were strings. With the method `pandas.DataFrame.sort_index` the indices ending in '11' preceded indices ending in '2'. I was able to solve it with [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) package and [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method.

```py
import pandas as pd
import natsort
# create a df
df = pd.DataFrame(0,
    index=['Scaf11', 'Scaf5', 'Scaf1', 'Scaf101'],
    columns=['Scaf11', 'Scaf5', 'Scaf1', 'Scaf101'])
# sort columns of the df
df = df.reindex(columns=natsort.humansorted(df.columns))
# sort indices of the df
df = df.reindex(index=natsort.humansorted(df.index))
```

Resulting in these dataframes:

```
# created dataframe
         Scaf11  Scaf5  Scaf1  Scaf101
Scaf11        0      0      0        0
Scaf5         0      0      0        0
Scaf1         0      0      0        0
Scaf101       0      0      0        0
# sorted dataframe (both for cols and indices)
         Scaf1  Scaf5  Scaf11  Scaf101
Scaf1        0      0       0        0
Scaf5        0      0       0        0
Scaf11       0      0       0        0
Scaf101      0      0       0        0
```

I'd recommend having a look at `reindex` documentation. It is useful to reorder the indices or add new indices in a precise position of the dataframe. `natsort` is useful to naturally sort a list of strings, for example. It may offer more methods of sorting in its documentation.